# Using a dataset of fruits, determine how many strawberries were sold that day

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I am wanting to isolate the column 'sold count'.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please post the actual codes and printed output, such as `print(your_df)`.

Comment: `df.groupby('fruit name')['sold count'].sum()`

Answer (score 0):

```
total_strawberries = inventory[inventory['fruit name'] == 'strawberry']
total_strawberries = total_strawberries.groupby('fruit name').sum()
***total_strawberries = total_strawberries.get('sold count').loc['strawberry']***
total_strawberries
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.